# Spring Boot application.yml and application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to understand if I have some properties in application.yml and a few in application.properties will my application read from both these files?

Comment: why don't you give it a try and check

Answer (score 2):

According to [Spring documentation - Change the Location of External Properties of an Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties):

*No matter what you set in the environment, Spring Boot always loads application.properties as described above. By default, if YAML is used, then files with the ‘.yml’ extension are also added to the list.*

In which order properties are considered is explained in the chapter [Spring documentation - Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

If in doubt what files have been loaded I recommend to set the log level to `DEBUG` which shows the loaded configuration files in the log.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/), that describes how both of these can be read using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

`@ConfigurationProperties` supports both `.properties` and `.yml` files.
`@ConfigurationProperties` support `JSR-303` bean validation – `javax.validation`

Hope this helps!